# render api response array object on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch some data from API and loop through the parsed response content and render them.

But I am getting a warning

```
webpackHotDevClient.js:138 ./src/App.js

Line 20:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Here's my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './Api.css';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var listItems;
    request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);
    request.onload = function () {

      // Begin accessing JSON data here
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) 
      {
            listItems = data.forEach(movie => {
                <div className="card">
                    <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
                    <p>{movie.description}</p>
                </div>
            });
      } 
      else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    }

    request.send();

    return (
    <div className="App">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <div className="container">
            {listItems}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I try to `console.log(listItems)` after `request.send()` I get `undefined`.

I assume `undefined` issue could be because of `asynchronous` behavior.
How can I render these elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render` method is not a suitable place to make asynchronous requests. You should move fetching code in a suitable lifecycle method like `componentDidMount`, or use a function then call this from `componentDidmount`. Then, using the component state you need to put this fetched data in your state.

The warning is coming from the linter. You are using `forEach` and `forEach` does not return anything. This is why the warning says it expects an assignment or a function call there. Instead of `forEach`, you should use `map` for creating JSX elements.

For the `undefined` part, you guessed it right. Your request is asynchronous and your render method does not wait for the asynchronous request to finish its job, wants to render `listItems` immediately but there are no `listItems` yet :) This is why we are using React's one of the best parts: the state and lifecycle methods.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { movies: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getItems();
  }

  getItems = () => {
    const that = this;
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films", true);
    request.onload = function get() {
      const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        that.setState({ movies: data });
      } else {
        console.log("error");
      }
    };

    request.send();
  };

  listItems = () =>
    this.state.movies.map(movie => (
      <div className="card">
        <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
        <p>{movie.description}</p>
      </div>
    ));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">{this.listItems()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome @Azima. I've updated my answer a little bit. I think it is more clear right now.

Comment: one more thing, why did you use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`? since `componentDidMount` hook is called after render method only.

Comment: For two reasons. 1. `render` method doesn't wait for `componentWillMount`. So, there is no difference between using `componentDidMount` or it. 2. `componentWillMount` will be deprecated in a future release :) https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: listItems = () =>
    *return* this.state.movies.map(movie => (
      <div className="card">
        <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
        <p>{movie.description}</p>
      </div>
    ));

It should be returned, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @KarthikRajan, it is an arrow function and has an implicit return. If you use `return` then you should use a body block there. [See for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body).